# IE 8 compatibility issues with trim and indexof

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, x-ua-compatible

My website is viewing perfectly fine in latest Firefox versions, chrome versions, and IE 9 and above. But the problem begins when it is opened in IE 8.

On debugging I explored that IE 8 does not support string functions like `.trim`, `.indexof` etc. So I have to find alternate methods for each string function.

But I have used these functions alot almost in every js.

I read on the net that this compatibility issue can be resolved by adding some meta tag in the head section. (x-ua-compatible).

Answer (score 1):

You are right, `.indexOf` doesn't work for IE8 or less. You can use jQuery's `$.inArray()` `$.trim()` instead.